# Breaking out of while loop with a switch case inside

Tags: bash, scripting, inotify

I am having an issue with exiting a bash script out of a while loop:

```
while read -r dir event name; do
  case $event in
    OPEN)
    chown $VHOST:$VHOST $WEBPATH/$name;
    echo "The file \"$name\" was created (not necessarily writable)";
    ;;
    WRITE)
    echo "The file \"$name\" was written to";
    ;;
    DELETE)
    echo "The file \"$name\" was deleted";
    exit 0;
    ;;
  esac
done < <(/usr/bin/inotifywait -m $WEBPATH)
```

The loop correctly listens for file changes in the given Directory, so far so good.

This also shows on the console output:

```
root #: bash /var/scriptusr/letsencrypt/dir-change
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
The file "tes" was created (not necessarily writable)
The file "tes" was deleted
root #:
```

Apparently it seems the script exited nicely but when you search for it in the process tree it is still there:

```
root #: ps aux | grep dir-
root      5549  0.0  0.0  14700  1716 pts/0    S    14:46   0:00 bash /var/scriptusr/letsencrypt/dir-change
root      5558  0.0  0.0  14184  2184 pts/1    S+   14:46   0:00 grep dir-
root #:
```

So my question is how to really exit the script?

Comment: isn't that your inotify subshell?

Comment: @mikeserv Yeah, you're right. But I didnt't know any other way of of watching for the file Change. Because without the "-m" parameter, inotifywait would exit the moment the file is created. But I to chown this specific file the moment it is created... That's my problem...

Comment: what i mean is, the reason its still running is because it is a subscriber to a kernel service. you need to end its subscription. im not very familiar with inotifywait, but almost definitely there is some signal or timeout or whatever for the subscribed process to *stop* listening.

Comment: Note that OPEN doesn't necessarily mean the file was created.

Comment: @chepner Taken note of it and changed the switch to CREATE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution after searching for a bit.

The problem originates from `inotifywait` going subshell as @mikeserv stated in the comments above.

So I had to write a cleanup method for it. My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
# script for immediatly changing the owner and group of the let's encrypt challenge file in the given webroot

Pidfile="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"/run-file-chowner.pid
echo $$ > $Pidfile

function terminate_process () {
        trap - SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT
        printf "\nTerminating process...\n"
        rm "$Pidfile" > /dev/null 2>&1;
        kill -- -$$
        exit $1
}

function main () {

trap terminate_process SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT

local OPTIND D opt

while getopts D: opt;
do
        case $opt in
        D)
                Domain=$OPTARG;;
        esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

case $Domain in
        'domain-b.com')
                VHost="doma-www"
        ;;
        'domain-a.com')
                VHost="domb-www"
        ;;
        *)
                printf "\nScript usage : [ $0 -D \"example.com\" ]\n\n"
                exit 1;
        ;;
esac

WebPath=/var/www/$Domain/$VHost/htdocs/public/.well-known/acme-challenge

inotifywait -m $WebPath | while read -r dir event name; do
        case $event in
        CREATE)
                chown $VHost:$VHost $WebPath/$name
                printf "\nOwner and group of \"$name\" were changed to $VHost...\n"
        ;;
        DELETE)
                printf "\nThe file \"$name\" was deleted\n"
                terminate_process 0
        ;;
        *)
                printf "\nEvent $event was triggered.\n"
        ;;
        esac
done
}

main "$@"
```

In this is the output, when a file in the watched folder is created and deleted:

```
root #: bash file-chowner -D dom-a.com
Setting up watches.
Watches established.

Owner and group of "test" were changed to doma-www...

Event OPEN was triggered.

Event ATTRIB was triggered.

Event CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE was triggered.

Event ATTRIB was triggered.

The file "test" was deleted

Terminating process...
Terminated

Terminating process...
Terminated
```

Comment: that's a really good answer! just a note in case you're unaware: the `function` keyword when used with `()` for a function definition serves no purpose except to make your script less portable. the `function` keyword automatically automatically ignores the definition anyway and it winds up parsed as if the `function` keyword were not used at all. but your script is really good - and i think its awesome you came back to answer your own question. 9 times out of 10, these are the best answers.

Comment: @mikeserv I already removed the brackets according to your explanation. Thank you for your help and comments along this lttle script!

Comment: i don't know if you fully understood me: what i was suggesting was just that you do `main(){ ...; }` rather than `function main(){ ...; }` because the latter form doesn't work in as many host shells as the former, and the latter doesn't offer any advantage over the former in those in which it does. the other way to do it is `function main { ...; }` but that is only useful if you want to localize `trap`s and variables per function. the variables can be fairly portably localized with the `local` builtin declaration command, anyway, by the way.

Comment: Good thing you clarified it for me. I really did missunderstand. After a bit of reading I agree with you, it's not that portable. Another thing for me to remember!